# Understand how Spark is transforming input file to worker nodes

Tags: apache-spark

I have a Spark cluster with 3 worker nodes. Take the simplified word count as sample:

```
val textFile = sc.textFile("hdfs://input/words")
textFile.count
```

This application is creating a RDD, and calculating how many lines. Due to the input file is huge, when actually performing `count` function, does Spark splits the input into 3 parts and separately move them to the 3 worker nodes? If so, how does Spark partition the input file (how Spark determine which line send to which worker node)?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to process file "hdfs://input/words". This file is already split as soon as you store it on HDFS(Since you have taken example of HDFS file above). If file has 3 blocks, Spark will see it as 3 partitions of file.
Spark does not need to move file to worker nodes. since file is on HDFS. it is already on machines which will be used as worker nodes by spark. 
I hope this is clear.

Comment: Thanks! So if the input file is stored in HDFS, they are already split into worker nodes. But how about S3 file?